# prawn pdf table generation breaking a new page too early?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, prawn

I'm using Prawn to generate pdf's and displaying data in a table. My problem is if a row is to large the page breaks and adds this entire row on a new page. With continuing rows underneath it. Hence I'm being left with big empty spaces under certain pages. Like 5 rows listed and then a large empty space - page break - on new page show large row(That wouldn't fit in its entirety on the page before) + continue showing other rows.

```
Prawn::Document.generate("#{filename}", :page_layout => :portrait) do
#table
  table_rows_count = statement_table.size
  table(statement_table) do |s_table|
  all the code to format table contents
end
```

What I'm trying to do, is have the row break a new page when it reaches the end of that page and then display the rest of that row on the other page. i.e making full use of the space available on a specific page before creating a new one.

I have tried grouping the entire table. But that doesn't work - prawn won't allow it.

Any ideas? I'd very much appreciate your help.